# how i can make SVG clickable to trigger a function?

Tags: reactjs, svg, bootstrap-5

I have a card in which I've added SVG from bootstrap. I want to change the content of the card when the SVG is clicked. In a way i want to use svg as button.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bar-chart-line" viewBox="0 0 16 16" onClick={showStatHandler}>
  <path d="M11 2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3h1V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7h1V2zm1 12h2V2h-2v12zm-3 0V7H7v7h2zm-5 0v-3H2v3h2z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<svg onClick={handleClick}>`?

Comment: yes i have but it is not making it clickable in reactapp

Comment: It does. It will not change the cursor for you though. You need to apply some css for that.

Comment: Also, please include a code exmaple of what you have tried.

Comment: Can you please explain it with example?

Comment: No. But you can show me an example where it's not working in a code sandbox or something. I just tried it and it work like expected for me.

Comment: yes it worked, there was problem with div. thank you for answering

Answer (score -1):

you can get a listener to your SVG by doing smth like

```
document.querySelector('svg').onclick = () => {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to make it clickable in react app ?